# NetfilterQueue tiped "are you root " ,which I was already the "root"

Tags: python-2.7, root, ubuntu-16.04, canopy, netfilter

After successfully importing netfilterqueue, when executing`NetfilterQueue()` then I encountered an error

`nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
File "netfilterqueue.pyx", line 153, in netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue.__cinit__ (netfilterqueue.c:3733)
OSError: Failed to bind family 2. Are you root?`

My environment is as below:

- Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64
- Python 2.7.11(Canopy)

Questions:

1. 'netfilterqueue.pyx' might be here:[git link](https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue/blob/master/netfilterqueue.pyx), how should I solve it?
2. If I was not the root, how should I get a "root" access while I was in the python command line?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing python interpreter as root before executing your code

```
sudo python
>>> import netfilterqueue
>>> nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
```